# Adding Audio instead of <object> in HTML4.1

Tags: javascript, css, html, audio

I have Orekaweb a audio recorder. It runs on Apache tomcat. What it does is it records all calls on VOIP network and provides a easy access to view them on web browser.

The issue is the recorded calls are in WAV format and it works perfect in IE. the codes are.

```
<td colspan="2">

<script language="JavaScript">
function play (audioFilename)
{
document.all.player.autoStart = true;
document.all.player.fileName = audioFilename;
}
</script>

<OBJECT ID="player"
CLASSID="CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95"
CODEBASE="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/
en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701"
STANDBY="Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components..."
TYPE="application/x-oleobject"
WIDTH=280 HEIGHT=50 >
<PARAM NAME="fileName" VALUE="">
<PARAM NAME="animationatStart" VALUE="false">
<PARAM NAME="transparentatStart" VALUE="true">
<PARAM NAME="showControls" VALUE="true">
<PARAM NAME="ShowStatusBar" VALUE="true">
<PARAM NAME="ShowDisplay" VALUE="false">
<PARAM NAME="ShowPositionControls" VALUE="true">
<PARAM NAME="ShowTracker" VALUE="true">
<PARAM NAME="CurrentPosition" VALUE="0">
<PARAM NAME="autoStart" VALUE="true">
</OBJECT>
```

The audio play back function is not playing on Google chrome or other browsers.

So i thought of adding up  inbuilt webkit player.

I added up the codes its below.

```
<td colspan="2">

<script language="JavaScript">
function play (audioFilename)
{
document.all.player.autoStart = true;
document.all.player.fileName = audioFilename;
}
</script>
<audio width="280" height="50" controls="controls" src="audiofileName" >
<object width="280" height="50" type="audio/x-wav" data="audiofileName">
<PARAM NAME="fileName" VALUE="">
<!-- Image as a last resort -->
</object>
</audio>
```

I see the player, but its playing.

Can anyone help me in this regards.

Stephen Paulraj

Comment: You need to rewrite your JavaScript to use the standard API. Everything about your current JS is either IE specific or specific to the ActiveX control you were using.